# Remove [message] and [messages]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, burninate-request

[message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/message) (1700+) and [messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/messages) (600+) are too ambiguous to be useful. There are also cases where some re-tagging needs to happen, like [facebook-message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-message) with [these posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/message+facebook).

Related: [Tag Merge Request: [messages] and [message]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142655/tag-merge-request-messages-and-message)

Comment: At the least they should be merged, but not every language and platform has its own tag.

Comment: LOL, I was about to post this. That front page question had pretty useless tags, I'll admit. While we're at it, let's also get rid of [tag:enter]

Answer (score -1):

These should at least be merged. The [send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/send) tag should probably join them.

Comment: Huh. That reduces some questions by two tags... linke this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030682/how-to-enable-enter-button-to-send-messages

Comment: @Deduplicator, that was the question that inspired this answer.

Comment: That is funny .