# Merge or change description of [messenger] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

There's quite a few questions tagged with [messenger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/messenger) that aren't about Facebook's messenger even though the description for the tag is "Allow sharing content from your app into Facebook Messenger.".

There's also the [facebook-messenger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-messenger) tag which is for the exact same application.

Comment: The tags shouldn't be merged until we clean up the questions that aren't using it to mean "FB Messenger". But after that, it seems like a good idea.

Comment: I have edited the question into a retag-request; [tag:messenger] could easily be used for something else in the future, but all currently tagged questions are likely good candidates for [tag:facebook-messenger].

Answer (score 2):

As of March 5, 2023

- [messenger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/messenger) has 769 questions
- [[facebook][messenger] is:question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmessenger%5D%5Bfacebook%5D%20is%3Aquestion) returns 353 results
- [[messenger][facebook][facebook-messenger] is:question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmessenger%5D%5Bfacebook%5D%5Bfacebook-messenger%5D+is%3Aquestion) returns 86 results

Another related tag is [facebook-messenger-bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-messenger-bot)

Related

- [Remove [message] and [messages]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266507/1595451)
- [Let's stop [Chat]tering](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314235/1595451)
- [Persistent trouble: [messaging] [messages] with these tags sends the wrong [message]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356647/1595451)

Comment: Just a bit more information regarding questions without the [tag:facebook] tag: There are 5 questions without the facebook tag, but with "facebook" in both the title and body; 4 questions without the facebook tag, but with "facebook" in the title, but not the body; and 72 questions without the facebook tag, but with "facebook" in the body, but not the title.