# Persistent trouble: [messaging] [messages] with these tags sends the wrong [message]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, retag-request, blocklist-request

The tags [message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/message) (2606 questions) and [messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/messages) (926 questions) have been subject to multiple discussions.

A merge request has been posted [on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142655/tag-merge-request-messages-and-message) in 2012, and the only comment on it suggests it should be burninated.

Then, in 2014, a burninate request has been made [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266507/remove-message-and-messages), and the only answer there suggests they should be merged.

And now, let's add a third contender to the mix: [messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/messaging) (1968 questions), and perhaps actually undertake action, because they're still around.

**The case for burnination:**

All these tags are ambiguous, the tag description of [messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/messages) covers the ambiguity well:

> a communication containing some information, news, advice, request, or the like, sent by messenger, radio, telephone, or other means.

Some uses of the tags may be on-topic, but lots of other uses aren't. The concept is  just too broad. For questions that have appropriate specific tags, the tags add little to nothing to the posts. They also don't mean the same across all common context, as using messages to communicate between client and server is totally different from UI messages and such.

The more subjective reason not to burninate, can you be an expert in it, of course, is true, but experts in messaging might work at a postal company delivering mail.

**The case for blacklisting:**

These tags are broad, widely used, and have the been subject of multiple discussions. I predict the chance they will recur if we burninate them to be large.

**The case for merging:**

This case is a weak one, because the case for burninating is strong, but they essentially all mean the same, so a merge is really appropriate, but why merge a tag and then burninate it?

Well, burninating them all will take time and effort, and merging them first might provide both a temporary improvement, and might help burninate efforts.

Comment: still I didn't get a [tag:message]

Comment: "but experts in messaging might work at a postal company delivering mail." beware, you may anger the [tag:mailman]

Comment: Maybe post three answer proposing each option, that way people can vote on what they think the correct option would be.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Implemented your suggestion. Feel free to vote on one, and rewrite it to fit your thoughts. I can't agree with all options, since I do have my preferences, but tried to make a case for all of them.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf actually, that's not recommended.

Comment: @Braiam  Details and link to what is recommended?

Answer (score 13):

*(Posting separate answers for all the options, so you can vote per option, per [Dijkgraaf](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2571021/dijkgraaf)'s suggestion. Feel free to edit them and add arguments)*

**We should burninate AND blacklist the tags**

Blacklisting is appropriate for these tags, since they are frequently used, and likely to recur. If we don't blacklist these tags, we're likely to have this discussion again, and since this is already the third time action is requested on this tag (third time's the charm) let's let them stay gone forever now.

Comment: I vote for burninating and blacklisting `message` and `messages`. The tagged questions do not form a useful set. However, I am not sure with [`messaging`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/messaging). The tagged questions actually seem to build a sensible group with the topic sending and receiving messages as a valid programming task. Some techniques in this area should be valid independently on the used language or framework, so the tag looks reasonable to me.

Comment: @Melebius certainly an interesting argument, but I fear misuse will increase once we blacklist those other tags (misuse is already present, though not widespread). Maybe a retag to something more descriptive or a [how-to-ask tip](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274632/help-the-helpless-with-how-to-ask-tag-tips) can fix that. It does complicate this call to action, though.

Answer (score 5):

*(Posting separate answers for all the options, so you can vote per option, per [Dijkgraaf](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2571021/dijkgraaf)'s suggestion. Feel free to edit them and add arguments)*

**We should merge them, before anything else**

Merging the tags organizes them under one tag. This makes any other effort easier, and is appropriate, because all tags essentially mean the same.

Since burninating the tags is a long process for tags with that many questions (and perhaps isn't even necessary), merging them is the priority.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posting separate answers for all the options, so you can vote per option, per [Dijkgraaf](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2571021/dijkgraaf)'s suggestion. Feel free to edit them and add arguments)*

**We should burninate the tags, but not blacklist them**

Burninating seems appropriate, but blacklisting may be excessive.

These tags haven't been burninated before, so we don't know if they will recur. Blacklisting should be reserved for tags that do recur